# How to add and print objects from csv to arrayList

Tags: java, csv, object, arraylist

I'm trying to add the product read from a CSV file to an ArrayList and create an object for each product. But when I try to print the arrayist using a for each loop, I'm keep getting the last element, in this case i get TV three times

my csv file:

car, 20000

table, 150

TV, 250

my product class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class product {
    private static String Name;
    private static double Price;
    public static List<product> List_product = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void readPrice() throws IOException {

        FileReader info = new FileReader("info.csv");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(info);
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            String[] attributes = line.split(",");      
            double price = Double.parseDouble(attributes[1]);
            List_product.add(new product(attributes[0], price));
        }
        reader.close(); 
    }

    public product(String Name, double Price) {
        product.Name = Name;
        product.Price = Price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public static List<product> getList() { 
        return List_product;
    }
}
```

my main:

```
    try {
        product.readPrice();
        for (product product : product.getList()) {
        System.out.println(product.getName()+"--"+product.getPrice());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: A debugger will help you fix it

Comment: FYI: Don't read a CSV with a `FileReader`, use an API like Apache Common CSV to read it properly. This is more complicated than a `String.split(",")`

Comment: You don't call readPrice() anywhere.

Comment: @DmitriiCheremisin you are right, I have to call it first, but the problem is that all the columns have the same value. In another way, the second value will overwrite the first one and so on. Any hints?

Comment: Please, explain how may it happen? I see that you use ArrayList for storing your product objects. This data structure allows duplicates. So, you may put in it as much equal objects as you want.

Comment: @DmitriiCheremisin  if I know I'd solve the problem. I'm getting the last element in the CSV file repeating. and I'm sure that the CSV file has different elements.

Comment: @csse please, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem is that you use **static** variables:

```
private static String Name;
private static double Price;
```

They belong to the class, not to the object you create. When you create last object - it overrides others.

So, right way of doing your task is to change your product class(please, use uppercase as it is code convention for naming classes)

```
class Product {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    public static List<Product> List_product = new ArrayList<>();

    public Product(String name, double price) {
       this.name = name;
       this.price = price;
    }
    //...other code is fine

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try This,
    Main.java
        try {
        Product.readPrice();
        for (Product product : Product.getList()) {
        System.out.println(product.getName()+"--"+product.getPrice());
        }
        }catch (IOException e) {
        }

       public class Product {    
       private String name;    
       private double price;    
       public static List<Product> listProduct = new ArrayList<>();    
       public static void readPrice() throws IOException {    
       FileReader info = new FileReader("info.csv");    
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(info);    
       while (true) {    
       String line = reader.readLine();    
       if (line == null) {    
       break;    
       }    
       String[] attributes = line.split(",");    
       double price = Double.parseDouble(attributes[1]);        
       listProduct.add(new Product(attributes[0], price));    
       }    
       reader.close();    
       }    
       public Product(String name, double price) {    
       this.name = name;    
       this.price = price;    
       }    
       public String getName() {    
       return name;    
       }    
       public double getPrice() {    
       return price;    
       }    
       public static List<Product> getList() {    
       return listProduct;    
       }    
       }
```

Comment: I'm getting the last element in the CSV file repeating. and I'm sure that the CSV file has different elements

Comment: Share sample csv file on my mail nandhacs7@gmail.com

Comment: Share sample csv file and sample output.

Comment: I sent you an email.